# emacsclient -nw and strikethrough text in org mode

Tags: org-mode, terminal-emacs

> https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html
>   You can make words `*bold*`, `/italic/`, `_underlined_`, `=code=` and `~verbatim~`, and, if you must, `+strike-through+`.

How to strikethrough a word, when writing something
in org mode

my env: emacs latest, -nw mode, terminal.app, macOS

Comment: Hum... Simply put `+` characters around the word? But this may not work inside a terminal. And actually just now I understand this is your question actually.

Comment: that didn't work, I mean visually I couldn't see the line

Answer (score 3):

Emacs 28 (master branch as of this writing) [recently gained support](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=e0e147e10389e407531ca81d0063a11a5716d765) for emitting the necessary ECMA-48 "Select Graphic Rendition" escape sequences in order to render faces with the 'strike-through' attribute on TTY frames.

If you're running a version of Emacs 28 that includes this commit, and your terminal's termcap/terminfo database entry has the `smxx` capability (included in more recent [xterm terminfo sources](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo-contents.html#tic-ecma_strikeout)) you should be able to see `+strike-through+` rendered properly in Org mode documents inside of TTY frames.

Comment: nice job whoever did it

Comment: `print -n -- '\e[9m'` works on my terminal; Does it need other stuff in its terminfo as well? The 24-bit colors also need some custom terminfo, so it would be good if there was an official source that released a complete terminfo.

Comment: @HappyFace: I made a custom terminfo that has both the 24-bit color entries as well as the entries for strike-through. The strike-through entries look like: `smxx=\E[9m, rmxx=\E[29m,`

Answer (score 1):

I want to supplement [JaenPierre's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/43725/2370) answer.

The evaluation of the following elisp code in the `*scratch*` buffer gives stricken-through text in Emacs with a GUI and non-stricken-through text in Emacs in terminal mode.

```el
(insert (propertize "hello world" 'font-lock-face '(:strike-through t)))
```

On the first glance it looks like `:strike-through` is not supported on `vt100` compatible terminals.

But in principle [vt100 supports stricken-through text](https://askubuntu.com/a/528938/275781) and the following elisp code returns `(("unspecified" . unspecified) ("t" . t) ("nil"))` in a `vt100` compatible terminal.

```el
(face-valid-attribute-values :strike-through)
```

AFAIK the cons `("t" . t)` in the return value says that stricken-through text should be supported. So at the second glance it looks more like a bug in Emacs.

Comment: yay I found a bug in emacs, my first one

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior You can try to issue a bug-report  by `M-x report-emacs-bug` with the above information and look what the guys at bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org answer about the problem. Maybe I am wrong and it is not a bug but expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of text in emacs is controlled by *faces*, describing various aspects of the display of characters.  The [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html#Face-Attributes) says:

> ### 37.12.1 Face Attributes
>
> “Face attributes” determine the visual appearance of a face.  The
>   following table lists all the face attributes, their possible values,
>   and their effects.
>
> ...
>
> Some of these attributes are meaningful only on certain kinds of
>   displays.  If your display cannot handle a certain attribute, the
>   attribute is ignored.
>
> ...
>
> ‘:strike-through’
>        Whether or not characters should be strike-through, and in what
>        color.

In your case the "display" is your text terminal and it seems to not support`:strike-through`. I don't know if any text terminal supports it, for example `xterm` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark a word or a sentence and press `C-c C-x C-f`. After that you can select your action. If you hit the <kbd>+</kbd> key, that selected word or sentence will be crossed out.